# when i use json.net,how to deserialize String to .net Object by customized JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json.net

For example, items in expressions may be a string, number, or an object. How to deserialize it to.NET `object`. I do not know how to define .NET class and do not know to implement `JsonConverter`.

```
{
    "target": {
        "propertyName": "AlertObjectInfo",
        "valueType": "string"
    },
    "source": {
        "operationName": "concat",
        "expressions": [
            "aa",
            "bb",
            2,
            {
                "operationName": "concat",
                "expressions": [
                    "Name",
                    "Tom"
                ]
            },
            {
                "operationName": "Add",
                "expressions": [
                    3,
                    4
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Json.NET has quiet a good documentation with examples: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm. Do you have trouble understanding the documentation? In that case, what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: basically to deserialize the json string, you need a class corresponding to the json (= your data model). If you are not sure what the class should look like, you can use helpful tools such as https://json2csharp.com/. With that it should be as easy as calling `Product deserializedItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataModel>(jsonstring);`

Comment: Why do you need to deserialize it? Can you show the full code how are you going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your json payload to a corresponding C# object(s). You can do this in Visual Studio using the [Paste Special](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2020/07/visual-studio-creating-class-from-json-data-using-paste-special-tool/) option under the edit menu or as noted you can use an [online tool](https://json2csharp.com/) to do the conversion.

This conversion will result in something like this based on your sample payload:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("target")]
    public Target Target { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("source")]
    public Source Source { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    [JsonPropertyName("operationName")]
    public string OperationName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("expressions")]
    public List<object> Expressions { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{
    [JsonPropertyName("propertyName")]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("valueType")]
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialize the json into c# objects you'll make a call like the following.

**System.Text.Json**

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

**NewtonSoft**

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

If you're using Newtonsoft you'll want to replace the `[JsonPropertyName("target")]` attributes with `[JsonProperty("target")]`